# Create rule in OpenWrt LuCi, apply saved iptables rule from command line

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openwrt

In the OpenWrt LuCi web interface, one can create rules but leave them disabled.

[image]

I have a rule for forwarding public web traffic to one of the hosts on my private network, but I usually leave it disabled.  When I want to enable it, I log into the LuCi web interface and click the enable button.

I can ssh to my OpenWrt device.  Is it possible to enable these saved rules from the command line?  For example, with the iptables command?  I don't see the disabled rule listed with

```
iptables -L -t NAT
```

Comment: How do you "disable" the rule, and/or how do you "enable" it? (Please [edit].)

Answer (score 2):

**Add new redirect section to firewall config**

it'll be latest in list of redirects sections
`uci add firewall redirect` - this will return you your new section name, for example - `cfgca3837`.
Then you should use that new section name for setting its attributes:

```
uci set firewall.cfgca3837.name='ssh to lan'
uci set firewall.cfgca3837.target=DNAT
uci set firewall.cfgca3837.src=wan
uci set firewall.cfgca3837.dest=lan
uci set firewall.cfgca3837.proto=tcp
uci set firewall.cfgca3837.dest_ip=192.168.0.110
uci set firewall.cfgca3837.src_dport=2222
uci set firewall.cfgca3837.dest_port=22
```

**Commit changes to firewall config**

```
uci commit firewall
```

**Revert changes to firewall config**

```
uci revert firewall
```

**Enable section 2 of redirects**

```
uci set firewall.@redirect[2].enabled=1
```

**Disable section 2 of redirects**

```
uci set firewall.@redirect[2].enabled=0
```

**Reorder section**, but it doesn't work well from CLI

```
uci reorder firewall.cfgca3837=2
```

**Show your new config section**

```
uci show firewall.cfgca3837
```

**Show pending changes in firewall config**

```
uci changes firewall
```

**Show section 2 of redirects in firewall config**

```
uci show firewall.@redirect[2]
```

**Show all firewall config**

```
uci show firewall
```

**Reload firewall rules**, it doesn't reload custom rules (/etc/firewall.user)

```
fw3 reload
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will try over the weekend and then send response.

Answer (score 1):

OPENWRT is adding to firewall config one line when the rule is disabled:
option enabled '0'
You need to edit /etc/config/firewall and add following line to the rule you want to disable. Then firewall has to be restarted.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see what you mean, but I haven't tried enabling and disabling yet.  I'm using chaos calmer r47608.  Will this option work with my version without applying any updates?